# PostgreSQL use value from previous row if missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, postgresql-9.1

I have a following query:

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', time_series) as trunc 
  FROM generate_series('2013-02-27 22:00'::timestamp, '2013-02-28 2:00', 
                       '1 hour') as time_series
  GROUP BY trunc
  ORDER BY trunc
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON(trunc) trunc, id
FROM t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id, created, date_trunc('hour', created) as trunc_u
   FROM event
   ORDER BY created DESC
) u
ON trunc = trunc_u
```

which yields the following result:

```
"2013-02-27 22:00:00";
"2013-02-27 23:00:00";2
"2013-02-28 00:00:00";5
"2013-02-28 01:00:00";
"2013-02-28 02:00:00";
```

Table `event` has `id`, `created` and some other columns, but only those are relevant here. The query above gives me `id` of last event generated per given `trunc` time period (thanks to `DISTINCT ON` I get a nice aggregation per period).

Now, this query yields `NULL` if no events happened in given time period. I would like it to return the previous available `id`, even if it is from different time period. I.e.:

```
"2013-02-27 22:00:00";0
"2013-02-27 23:00:00";2
"2013-02-28 00:00:00";5
"2013-02-28 01:00:00";5
"2013-02-28 02:00:00";5
```

I am sure I am missing some easy way to accomplish this. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT time_series as trunc 
    FROM generate_series('2013-02-27 22:00'::timestamp, '2013-02-28 2:00', 
                         '1 hour') as time_series
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON(t.trunc) t.trunc, e.id
  FROM t
  JOIN event e
    ON e.created < t.trunc 
 ORDER BY t.trunc, e.created DESC
```

If it is too slow - tell me. I will give you a faster query.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Speed is not much of a problem here, cause it is for reports, not often generated.

Comment: @Ihor what will be a faster query? I need exactly something like this, but for. +50 million rows on a regular basis ;) THX!

Answer (score 4):

You ca mix a self join and [windows functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

Simplifying I take this table with this sample values:

```
create table t ( a int, b int);    
insert into t values 
( 1, 1),
( 2, Null),
( 3, Null),
( 4, 2 ),
( 5, Null),
( 6, Null);
```

In your query `a` is `trunc_u` and `b` is your `id`. 
The query is:

```
with cte as (    
    select 
      t1.a, 
      coalesce( t1.b, t2.b, 0) as b,
      rank() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY t1.a ORDER BY t2.a DESC) as pos
    from t t1 
    left outer join t t2
      on t2.b is not null and
         t2.a < t1.a    
)
select a, b
from cte
where pos = 1;
```

And [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c5595/5/0):

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I think I'll use Igor's solution, because it's simpler.