# filling the null data by time series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
ts                    item          infoA         infoB         
2018-02-03 12:00:00   A             null          null          
2018-02-03 12:01:00   null          A1            null          
2018-02-03 12:02:00   A             null          null          
2018-02-03 12:03:00   null          null          null          
2018-02-03 12:04:00   null          A2            null           
2018-02-03 12:05:00   null          null          null         
2018-02-03 12:06:00   B             null          null         
2018-02-03 12:07:00   null          null          B1         
2018-02-03 12:08:00   null          null          null
```

I want to fill the null data with time series only on related item

```
ts                    item          infoA         infoB         
2018-02-03 12:00:00   A             null          null          
2018-02-03 12:01:00   A             A1            null          
2018-02-03 12:02:00   A             A1            null          
2018-02-03 12:03:00   A             A1            null          
2018-02-03 12:04:00   A             A2            null           
2018-02-03 12:05:00   A             A2            null         
2018-02-03 12:06:00   B             null          null         
2018-02-03 12:07:00   B             null          B1         
2018-02-03 12:08:00   B             null          B1
```

i found a AGGREGATE function GapFill() from 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073076/postgresql-fill-null-values-in-timeserie-query-with-previous-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Using the function, I can get the table from

```
select t1.ts, t1.item, t2.infoA, t3.infoB 
from 
(select ts,gapfill(item) OVER (ORDER BY ts)) t1 
LEFT JOIN (select ts,gapfill(infoA) OVER (ORDER BY ts) as infoA) on (t1.ts = t2.ts and t1.item='A') t2 
LEFT JOIN (select ts,gapfill(infoB) OVER (ORDER BY ts) as infoB) on (t1.ts = t3.ts and t1.item='B') t3
```

how can the query be simplified in case i have many column.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `ignore nulls` option on `lag()`.  But Postgres does not support it (yet).

Perhaps the simplest way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.ts,
       coalesce(item,
                (select t2.item
                 from t t2
                 where t2.ts < t.ts and t2.item is not null
                 order by t2.ts desc
                 fetch first 1 row only
                )
               ) as item,
       coalesce(itemA,
                (select t2.itemA
                 from t t2
                 where t2.ts < t.ts and t2.itemA is not null
                 order by t2.ts desc
                 fetch first 1 row only
                )
               ) as itemA,
       coalesce(itemB,
                (select t2.itemB
                 from t t2
                 where t2.ts < t.ts and t2.itemB is not null
                 order by t2.ts desc
                 fetch first 1 row only
                )
               ) as itemB
from t;
```

If you know the values are increasing or decreasing monotonically, you can use `max()` or `min()`.

Another method using window functions uses the same idea.  Identify the groups of rows with the same value by doing a cumulative count.  Then spread the value over the rows:

```
select t.ts,
           max(item) over (partition by grp_item) as item,
           max(itemA) over (partition by grp_item) as itemA,
           max(itemB) over (partition by grp_item) as itemB
from (select t.*,
                    count(item) over (order by ts) as grp_item,
                    count(itemA) over (order by ts) as grp_itemA,
                    count(itemB) over (order by ts) as grp_itemB
         from t
       ) t;
```