# how combine two different timeline in SQL

Tags: sql

there is a question confused me for a long time;

I have two log tables, one records product sell status (for sell=1, otherwise=0),

the other one records the product is out of stock or not(oos(out of stock)=1,otherwise=0);

here is tables schema:

source table schema, and final result schema

[image]

two timelines need to combine 1, and the last one is the final result

[image]

How to get this result by using **SQL**? I tried many times, but still cannot get answers.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll `FULL OUTER JOIN` the two tables in order to get all start times. The end time is the following time, which you get with `LEAD`. For the last row you make this '23:59' with `COALESCE`.

The nulls you are getting because of the full join mean "no new information", so you access the latest information there is, which you get with `LAST VALUE(... IGNORE NULLS)`.

```
select
  sku,
  utime as start_time,
  coalesce(lead(utime) over (partition by sku order by utime), '23:59') as end_time,
  last_value(sell.status ignore nulls) over (partition by sku order by utime) as sell_status,
  last_value(stock.is_oos ignore nulls) over (partition by sku order by utime) as is_out_of_stock
from sell full outer join stock using (sku, utime)
order by sku, start_time;
```

I don't know which DBMS you are using. The above query is standard SQL. Your DBMS may support all mentioned features (Oracle for example does) or it may not (MySQL for instance does not yet support full outer joins). If your DBMS lacks features used in my query, then look up stackoverflow or the Internet in general on how to emulate the missing feature in your DBMS.

Comment: for postgres 11 users - it does not support `last_value(... ignore nulls)`, but you can work around this limitation by leveraging https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074838/38749