# SQL Desired Result - window functions? Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm in need of adding an additional column onto the below result set. I have columns 1 and 2. Column 3 is the field I would like  to create using sql (Postgres). I'm familiar with how to use python to loop through the records one at a time to apply some conditional. However, I'm wondering if  there is a way to accomplish this in SQL. I've worked some with window functions. Can't find something to partition by effectively, or can't see how to filter. Was thinking I could go back a few records using "rows  preceding and current row" pulling a max, to no avail. Has anyone been able to do this? Essentially, the new field will switch  from 1 to 0 based on the 1  or -1. If it switches to 1 based on the 1 from the value column, it will stay 1 until it comes across a -1. Then it will stay 0, until it comes to a 1 in the value. Essentially a buy sell signal.

dataset:

| Date | Value | Trying to get this? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/7/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 2/8/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 2/13/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/14/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 2/15/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/19/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/20/2022 | -1 | 0 |
| 2/21/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 2/23/2022 | -1 | 0 |
| 2/24/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 2/25/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 2/26/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/27/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2/28/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 3/1/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/2/2022 | -1 | 0 |
| 3/3/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/4/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/5/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/6/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 3/7/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/13/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/14/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/15/2022 | -1 | 0 |
| 3/16/2022 | -1 | 0 |

Comment: what's the logic  for that column??

Comment: It is based on a signal to buy or sell stocks based on the Bollinger Bands technique. https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/technical-analysis/technical-indicator-guide/bollinger-bands

Comment: The 1 is  a signal to buy when the SMA moves below the lower band. The sell signal is when it moves above the upper band.

Comment: http://tomaslind.net/2013/11/12/bollinger-bands-in-t-sql/#:~:text=Bollinger%20Bands%C2%AE%20is%20a,and%20under%20this%20moving%20average. does this link help you.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I saw that. What I'm trying to do is interpret the buy and sell signals in SQL. I've created the SMA and other bands that make up the Bollinger Bands. I'm just trying to create a position strategy field.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073076/postgresql-fill-null-values-in-timeserie-query-with-previous-value